# Logical syntax of vacuity

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-explanation, first-order-logic

I was taught that vacuously true statements are of the form $P \implies Q$ where $P$ is a false statement. This property is routinely used to make claims about the empty-set.

Consider the function $f: \emptyset \to A$ where $A$ is a non-empty set. We have that $f$ is a function. Consequently, it satisfies the condition that $(\forall x \in \emptyset)(\exists y \in A) (x,y) \in f$. It is contended that this condition is satisfied vacuously.

How would I parse the above condition in an if-then statement so as to be able to apply the properties of material implication and conclude the vacuousness of the statement?

Comment: $\forall x \exists y [(x \in \emptyset \land y \in A) \to (x,y) \in f]$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA But what about the case $f: A \to \emptyset$? We know such a relation fails to satisfy left-totality (the above condition) and thus can not be a function. But parsing it as per your suggestion, we have that $$\forall x \exists y[ (x \in A \land y \in \emptyset) \to (x,y) \in f]$$ which would be vacuously true since the antecedent is false.

Comment: How about $\forall x\left[x\in\varnothing\to\exists y\in A\;\left(x,y\right)\in f\right]$?

Comment: @drhab Then we have a problem parsing the many-to-one property of a function $f: A \to \emptyset$. 
We have that $(\forall x \in A)(\forall y_1,y_2 \in \emptyset) (x,y_1),(x,y_2) \in f \implies y_1 = y_2$. 
Thus we will end up getting (as per your suggestion)
$$\forall x [ x\in A \implies \big((\forall y_1,y_2 \in \emptyset) (x,y_1),(x,y_2) \in f \implies y_1 = y_2 \big)]
$$ 
I am unsure if it is correct.
Secondly, I could not find anywhere that suggested that 
$$\big((\forall x \in A)(\exists y \in B) ... \big)\iff \forall x [x \in A \to \exists y \in B ...]
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A,B,f$ be sets.

Then $f$ is a function $A\to B$ if and only $f\subseteq A\times B$ and
$\forall x\left[x\in A\to\exists!y\left[\left(x,y\right)\in f\right]\right]$

If $A=\varnothing$ then $f=\varnothing$ acccording to the first
condition.

Further we observe that: $$x\in\varnothing\to\exists!y\left[\left(x,y\right)\in f\right]$$
is *vacuously* true, and this for *every* $x$.

Comment: As a generalization, is it always correct to say ∀x ∈A ∃y ∈B P(x,y) <=> ∀x [ x ∈A → ∃y ∈B P(x,y)]?

Comment: Yes. Actually $\forall x\in A\;Q(x)$ is an abbreviation of $\forall x[x\in A\to Q(x)]$. It you take $Q(x):=\exists y\in B\;P(x,y)$ then we get the statement you mention.

Answer (score 0):

Theorem: $\forall A: \exists f: \forall a: [a\in \emptyset \implies f(a)\in A]$

Hint: Use $f=\emptyset \times A$. Prove (vacuously):

1. $\forall a, b: [(a,b)\in f \implies a\in \emptyset \land b\in A]$
2. $\forall a: [a\in \emptyset \implies \exists b: [b\in A
       \land(a,b)\in f]]$
3. $\forall a, b, c: [a\in \emptyset \land b\in A \land c \in A
       \implies [(a,b)\in f \land (a,c)\in f \implies b=c]]$

Answer (score 0):

- Your question comes from the fact that your proposition is stated in ***abbreviated form***  " for all x belonging to the empty set" ( in the frst parenthesis). ***This " present participle" ( namely: " belonging")  hides an " if...then ".***
- Example : "All man having a son or a daughter is a father" has to be translated, in logical language ( with the set of male men as universal set) as :

  ```
         for all x [( IF x has a son or a daughter) THEN (x is a father)]
  ```

---

The statement defining a relation R as function from A to B is :

for all x, [ ( x belongs to A) --> ( there is some unique y in B such that xRy) ].

Substitute the empty set for A.

In that case, the antecedent of the conditional, namely, " x belongs to A" , is necessarily false.

So, whatever the truth value of the consequent might be, the whole conditional is true.